# Inconsistent token handling in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

The ANTLR4 book references a multi-mode example

https://github.com/stfairy/learn-antlr4/blob/master/tpantlr2-code/lexmagic/ModeTagsLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar ModeTagsLexer;

// Default mode rules (the SEA)
OPEN  : '<'     -> mode(ISLAND) ;       // switch to ISLAND mode
TEXT  : ~'<'+ ;                         // clump all text together

mode ISLAND;
CLOSE : '>'     -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // back to SEA mode 
SLASH : '/' ;
ID    : [a-zA-Z]+ ;                     // match/send ID in tag to parser
```

https://github.com/stfairy/learn-antlr4/blob/master/tpantlr2-code/lexmagic/ModeTagsParser.g4

```
parser grammar ModeTagsParser;

options { tokenVocab=ModeTagsLexer; } // use tokens from ModeTagsLexer.g4

file: (tag | TEXT)* ;

tag : '<' ID '>'
    | '<' '/' ID '>'
    ;
```

I'm trying to build on this example, but using the `«` and `»` characters for delimiters. If I simply substitute I'm getting error 126

`cannot create implicit token for string literal in non-combined grammar: '«'`

In fact, this seems to occur as soon as I have the `«` character in the parser `tag` rule.

```
tag : '«' ID '>';
```

with

```
OPEN    : '«'   -> pushMode(ISLAND);
TEXT    : ~'«'+;
```

Is there some antlr foo I'm missing? This is using `antlr4-maven-plugin` `4.2`.

The wiki mentions something along these lines, but the way I read it that's contradicting the example on github and anecdotal experience when using `<`. See "Redundant String Literals" at https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following is happening:

1. You forgot to update the `OPEN` rule in **ModeTagsLexer.g4** to use the following form:

   ```
   OPEN  : '«' -> mode(ISLAND) ;
   ```
2. You found a bug in ANTLR 4, which should be reported to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues).

Comment: I certainly updated the OPEN rule, the second snippet above was a cut/paste. I'll try to knock up a test case for a ticket. Thanks

Comment: It's looking like an issue with the antlr4-maven-plugin and/or m2e. I've not really been able to track it down any more than that. You know way more about this than I do, you may have better luck, see the example project https://github.com/ptomli/antlr4-22613293

Comment: FWIW, I created a ticket for this, eventually https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/563

Comment: I see you found and fixed the issue [https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/commit/156696be189bdf3929343fb4bea9b4fbe4a90063]. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the file encoding that ANTLR should use when reading the grammar? It should be okay with European characters less than 255 but...

Comment: Where, other than specifying the source/resources as UTF-8, might I be able to do this? See the example github repo where the breakage is repeatable https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/563

Comment: not sure about maven but typing "antlr4" on command line says:
 -encoding ___       specify grammar file encoding; e.g., euc-jp